# Javascript menu toggle not working on mobile devices after going live

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page that toggles a menu when clicked on the menu anchor. It is working well from mobile devices when hosted locally on xamp server, but just displays # when it is on the production server. Still, it works when I resized desktop window size, but not on my mobile. 
Here is my link to toggle a menu

```
<div class="menu-toggle">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        <span>Menu</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

And here is my js code

```
$('.menu-toggle > a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#responsive-nav').toggleClass('active');
    })
```

My CSS code is

```
.header-ctn .menu-toggle {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .header-ctn .menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  #responsive-nav {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #15161D;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 250px;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 22;
    padding-top: 60px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s all;
    transition: 0.2s all;
  }
  #responsive-nav.active {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
    transform: translateX(0%);
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I have included both my local js file and jquery file from CDN

Comment: displaying the # is normal behaviour, did you check the console on desktop on the production server? i think you might have some javascript errors there

Answer (score 0):

@GemeAlex

Can you please check the browser version in prod env and your local env. because toggle is very simple thing and as you said if it is working in your local, then i doubt it can be a version mismatch or the browser in prod env is not supporting the toggle.

Comment: What do you mean by browser version? I am using exact same chrome browser on both my desktop and my phone for both local and production server (when viewing my website)

Comment: I mean the version of the chrome browser. IT may be same browser but the version varies. you can check the Version under chrome - Help - About Chrome.

Comment: my desktop chrome version is 83.0.4103.97. But the problem is the menu toggle is working on both my phone and desktop when the web is on local server, it only does not work when hosted on live server. here is the link to my website https://www.ethiobookreview.com

Comment: So is this the working copy or this is having an issue with toggle? Coz.. I am not seeing any issue.. toggle is working absolutely fine. But yes there are console errors.

Comment: from here, the toggle is not working on mobile phones, but works on desktop when window is resized! but from local it does on both phones and desktop browsers!

Comment: resolved! I had to clear browsing history from my browser on phone! thank you for your time!

Answer (score -1):

You gave max-width: as 991px. So when you resize the browser more than 991px, the "#responsive-nav {" will not work.  change the max-width to 1440px. It will work in desktop view as well

Comment: this does not answer OP's question